# Как вывести результат цикла for в одну строку? (Без end='')

Tags: python, python-3.x

Самый простой пример:

```
for i in range(15):
    print(i)
```

Здесь выводится в столбик, а мне нужно чтобы выводилось в строку. Как это можно провернуть без `end=''`?

Comment: Чем не устраивает `end=''`?

Comment: Я на tkinter делаю интерфейс для моей программы, и я абсолютно без понятия как в label впихнуть end

Comment: Тогда стоило задать вопрос по tkinter, а не по print.

Comment: Похоже, Что Это [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/339283)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно распаковать значения списка.

***С пробелами:***

```py
print(*[x for x in range(15)])          # 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

---

***Без пробелов:***

```py
print(*[x for x in range(15)], sep='')  # 01234567891011121314
```

Comment: Распаковывать можно любые **iterable**.

Comment: можно еще так `print(''.join([str(x) for x in range(15)]))`

Answer (score -1):

```
nums = [12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,12,23,45,78]
alt_nums = []
for num in nums:
    num += 10
    alt_nums.append(num)
print(alt_nums)
```

Comment: поясните код)))